# Yii insert html in custom CListView

Tags: php, yii, widget

My problem: the two pagination options are on separate lines.

I have:

```
<div class="search_result searchconright">
    <?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'id' => 'listViewSearch',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'itemView' => '_index_post',
        'enablePagination' => true,
        'pager' => array(
                        'cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/clistview.css',
                        'header' => false,
                        'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
                        'prevPageLabel' => 'Previous',
                        'nextPageLabel' => 'Next',
                        'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
                    ),
        'summaryText' => '',
        'sortableAttributes' => array(
        ),
    ));
    ?>
</div>
<div class="pagetxt">
    <span>View</span>
    <a class="page_search_limit">All</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="page_search_limit page_search_limit_active">3</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a class="page_search_limit page_search_limit_active">5</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a class="page_search_limit page_search_limit_active">24</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a class="page_search_limit">48</a>
</div>
```

and i would like to insert the entire html from class pagetxt in the widget, because the seccond pagination, is under the widgets pagination; i would like them to be on the same line

also, other suggestions are welcomed

the pagination: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options, first the way you are doing it, you can use the [template](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#template-detail) property of CListView, to add the HTML where you want inside the widget.

But It looks like what you are trying to do, is to allow the user to specify the number of elements they want to see per page, so I'd recommend to use something like the [PageSize extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pagesize/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with CSS:

```
.search_result, .pagetxt {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

To change the CListView pagination HTML, you would have to create a new CLinkPager and the pass parameters to it. So I think CSS is way simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

This is purely a layout issue: you need to have the pager render inline with your custom HTML.

One way to do that would be to give `display: line-block` to both of these DIVs with CSS, but of course you can also use other techniques like floating.

You can easily target the stock pager by setting the `pagerCssClass` property on your list view; the default is simply `"pager"`, so you could do

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'id' => 'listViewSearch',
        'pagerCssClass' => 'pager pager-inline'
        // ...
);
```

and then for example

```
.pager.pager-inline, .pagetxt {
    display: inline-block;
}
```